# How to disable a Gradle task? (Spotless, OpenTelemetry)

Tags: gradle, open-telemetry, spotless, open-telemetry-java

**Problem :** Project linting task (Spotless-check) is too nitpicky and will not allow project to build

**Goal :** Trying disable the the spotless task when invoking `./gradelw assemble`

*(https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/gradlew)*

**Things I've tried**

- Manually editing the internal Gradle files
- Adding the `-x` flag to Gradle : ie.  `./gradlew assemble -x spotlessCheck`

**Result of attempts :** The code linting task runs regardless of everything I've tried to disable it.

Comment: Are you asking how to disable spotless in a Gradle build? Your question is not specific to OpenTelemetry, is it?

Comment: It is specific to the Opentelemetry project. But if you know of a general solution I'll try out what you have to offer @GaëlJ

Comment: That build is a raging mess. Just executing "clean" takes 6 minutes on a fast machine, because it somehow thinks it needs to execute everything, build an SBOM, and more just to remove some build directories. In a normal build, your approach would work.

Comment: is it the same with ./gradle assemble -x spotlessCheck instead of ./gradlew assemble -x spotlessCheck ?

Comment: @EricMartin same outcome

Answer (score 0):

I've had this spotless issue with many Java projects, so I think it's not specific to otel.
I think this feature needs to be added to spotless itself, so I'd open an issue there.

I usually just do `./gradlew spotlessApply` before running tests as a workaround.